# Convert String Into Dynamic Object

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is there a straightforward way of converting:

```
string str = "a=1,b=2,c=3";
```

into:

```
dynamic d = new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 };
```

I think I could probably write a function that splits the string and loops the results to create the dynamic object. I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: What do you expect the values to be ? Always `int` ?

Comment: @SimonL No, the values could be any data type.

Comment: When you say _any_, could this be classes as well ? Or just simple types (`string`s, number types)

Comment: @Simon: Just simple types such as string and number types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [Microsoft Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) ([here](http://nuget.org/packages/roslyn)'s the all-in-one NuGet package):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "a=1,b=2,c=3,d=\"4=four\"";
        string script = String.Format("new {{ {0} }}",str);
        var engine = new ScriptEngine();
        dynamic d = engine.CreateSession().Execute(script);
    }
}
```

And if you want to add even more complex types:

```
string str = "a=1,b=2,c=3,d=\"4=four\",e=Guid.NewGuid()";
...
engine.AddReference(typeof(System.Guid).Assembly);
engine.ImportNamespace("System");
...
dynamic d = engine.CreateSession().Execute(script);
```

Based on the question in your comment, there are code injection vulnerabilities. Add the `System` reference and namespace as shown right above, then replace the `str` with:

```
string str =
    @" a=1, oops = (new Func<int>(() => { 
                Console.WriteLine(
                    ""Security incident!!! User {0}\\{1} exposed "",
                    Environment.UserDomainName,
                    Environment.UserName); 
                return 1; 
            })).Invoke() ";
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I wonder if it opens up code injection vulnerabilities? Like escaping the string and executing random code similar to sql injection?

Answer (score 18):

I think if you convert the "=" into ":" and wrap everything with curly brackets you'll get a valid JSON string.

You can then use JSON.NET to deserialize it into a dynamic object:

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

You'll get what you want.

Comment: What if a string contains `=`

Comment: I think the question is about numbers only, anyways its just a suggestion.

Comment: I asked for clarifications earlier. See the original question's comments: it can be any simple types (including strings).

Comment: Well, the main idea could work, how he could convert the original value to json could be done in multiple ways.
Anyways I think Alex's answer is the best

Comment: It certainly could. I think using `JsonConvert` is the best alternative if you can overcome the translation to a proper Json string.

Answer (score 1):

The question you described is something like deserialization, that is, contructing objects from data form(like string, byte array, stream, etc). Hope this link helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) to store it after parsing it yourself. Right now it adds all values as `string`s, but you could add some parsing to try to turn it into a double, int, or long (you'd probably want to try it in that order).

```
static dynamic Parse(string str)
{
    IDictionary<String, Object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var assignment in str.Split(','))
    {
        var sections = assignment.Split('=');
        obj.Add(sections[0], sections[1]);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Use it like:

```
dynamic d = Parse("a=1,b=2,c=3");
// d.a is "1"
```

Comment: Again, the problem stems from the fact that a string could contain a `,`. Blindly splitting is not a good idea in this case. What if the input is: `a=1, b=2, c='This, my friend, is a string'`

Comment: Hm, good point; but for that matter, what exactly is this format? Is `'` a valid string separator? What about `"`? How do you escape those separators if you want one in the string? In short, I don't know that the format is very well-defined.

Comment: Agreed, we do not know much about the input and how it has been sanitized (and if he has control over it at all).

Comment: In any case, for simple number types and simple strings (ones that won't have any of these complicating factors), my solution will work. I don't know if this is sufficient or not, but it's better than nothing. :)